# How to use condition variables such that the sleeping thread doesn't miss the wakeup call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

Here the B thread issues a wake call but A thread doesn't wake up.

header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <thread>

class A
{
private:
    int someint;
public:
    void Run();
};

class B
{
public:
    void Run();
};

class ThreadManager
{
private:
    A obj_class_A_;
    B obj_class_B_;

    std::thread obj_thread_A_;
    std::thread obj_thread_B_;

public:
    ThreadManager();
    ~ThreadManager();
};

#endif // HEADER_H
```

source:

```
#include "thread_class.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

std::queue<int> queue_m;

std::mutex              mutex_x;
std::mutex              mutex_y;

std::condition_variable cv_x;
std::condition_variable cv_y;

ThreadManager::ThreadManager() : obj_thread_B_( &B::Run, &obj_class_B_),
                                 obj_thread_A_( &A::Run, &obj_class_A_ )
{
}

ThreadManager::~ThreadManager()
{
    obj_thread_A_.join();
    obj_thread_B_.join();
}

void A::Run()
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( mutex_x );
        cv_x.wait( lk );

        std::cout << "\nA class\n";

        someint++;
        queue_m.push( someint );

        cv_y.notify_all();

        // some long operation
        for (int t = 0; t < 10000000000000; t++) {}
    }
}

void B::Run()
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        std::cout << "\nB class\n";

        if (queue_m.size() > 0)
        {
            int temp = queue_m.front();
            std::cout << "\nTaken out: " << temp;
            queue_m.pop();

            cv_x.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            cv_x.notify_all();

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( mutex_y );
            cv_y.wait( lk );
        }
     }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "thread_class.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ThreadManager k;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to send notification `cv_y.notify_all();` after "some long operation" not before

Comment: @KillzoneKid won't do that since thread B is not concerned with that long operation.